# Problem deploying simple ruby sinatra app on heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku

I am new to ruby, git and heroku. I was trying to build a simple Hello World app and deploy it on heroku. I see the following error in the logs when I try to access the site using the heroku provided URL. Could you tell me what I am not doing right.

```
    2011-07-03T01:15:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    2011-07-03T01:15:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    2011-07-03T01:15:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
    2011-07-03T01:15:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `<main>'
    2011-07-03T01:15:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
    2011-07-03T01:15:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:175:in `load_rackup_config'
    2011-07-03T01:15:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
    2011-07-03T01:15:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:65:in `start'
    2011-07-03T01:15:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
    2011-07-03T01:15:06+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
    2011-07-03T01:15:07+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

config.ru file

```
    require 'myapp2'
    run Sinatra::Application
```

myapp2.rb

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'sinatra'

    get '/' do
    'Hello World'
    end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the top of the stack trace, but it looks like the problem is the `require`.

In `config.ru` change

```
require 'myapp2'
```

to

```
require './myapp2'
```

or

```
require File.expand_path("../myapp2", __FILE__)
```

Ruby 1.9.2 no longer has the current directory in the load path, so `require 'myapp2'` isn't able to find your app file which is in the same directory.

If this is working on your local machine, but not on Heroku, then you're likely using a different version of Ruby, probably 1.8.7. It would be a good idea to install 1.9.2 locally so that you're using the same version in development and production. Alternatively you could change the Heroku stack you're using; have a look at [the Heroku stack docs](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this and let you know.